# How to decrypt message with CryptoJS AES. I have a working Ruby example

Tags: javascript, ruby, aes, cryptojs

I'm able to decrypt AES encrypted message with Ruby like this:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

data = "IYkyGxYaNgHpnZWgwILMalVFmLWFgTCHCZL9263NOcfSo5lBjAzOZAtF5bF++R0Bi+9c9E+p3VEr/xvj4oABtRWVJ2wlWzLbYC2rKFk5iapFhb7uZCUpO4w4Su3a5QFa2vInjYueziRoqySZd/DpstMJ8rsJ94VGizFFFZ1l0sw1ax+wfBAv5+wHs/hlnHi/ea66KBO3rgXKahvV28h+4bh5etc8RCrmiiNbfg6Oj0jQJDjdYIdW8T9YPOI9E1hih8lbfRnMWcOFJgYekfLpoy5LI525UGnlM46J1k6ekLqsn9FqvbiOOoLgqa4YqBm1i9P0ePyjkME+t+RiL8xXX+ItgOYr9G7kM64wlTJPCW8B/crmUdmGzQNC/hD/u/8wfHBS2f8u6OtQMG/+Kpk1oju8lcUZGI/4S8A6/OuktvQr2zgnbs2aADMrM37Oait/pJ3G73S7NwVT8EaK+X43c0C/fUvW2/bD/rqCNpAh9WQlz4Cj6JHwjbmwuind6aCimF1tHjXuR9FXu+g17sPT4ZkKZ6aeBG+m170XdCGn2hVM0wH1rh3VeCG2u/JFqfuGKGSoqeHeNY/icu9pEhtZDzHd7aPoaMXcWvXC9PjooBf7GM1EPacSdnon1kBobjtKSt1l15DjO5TMrJoX7VO7GotQwo+uI/u5Kop01hBXxyxyggl1/8N0ESohPJoqLDrIwvbGK5kW4B49FVPnx9CMvjZDdSsoxPAh+hx6SPe8Hj0Nx4bRs06cbtOkte/V8QSYIqjiJDleEqPrdiKlvgToZz9L29ZR/3Ln65qU1sq7q9c0SEYxIopV7TdTjFS7y76zDPFZkhzc3DjfLtJo/M1hdtt648APcZdmAIgWH6fh3eJZ0qbiPh8RStYH7I2COmnlMw4+t/B5mlhYVSgwPK2Ir736Mh+P9Bw0fF8r9Ghhs4AJzpU0RiK9d1tCsrLfK/hSRwTXhtsSB6eDWEGkO7oeEIz43mgn0sv3SrA9JNHzYkg="
key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05"

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-128-cbc')
aes.decrypt
aes.key = key.scan(/../).collect{ |x| x.hex }.pack('c*')
aes.iv = Base64.decode64(data)[0...16]
puts aes.update(Base64.decode64(data)[16..-1]) + aes.final
# => JSON data...
```

Being new to CryptoJS I fail to put together working alternative. Here's what i've done so far:

```
data = "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";
key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05";

CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(atob(data).substring(16), key, {
    iv: atob(cipher).substring(0, 16),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```

Does CryptoJS expect data, key and initialization vector in some different way? As far as i understand, the IV are the first 16 bytes in data.

Comment: What error are you seeing? Or does it produce the wrong output?

Comment: When I run his code, his example produces the wrong output (as he describes).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This seems to work for me (writes decoded string to the console):

```
data = "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";
key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05";

// Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
var rawData = atob(data);
var iv = btoa(rawData.substring(0,16));
var crypttext = btoa(rawData.substring(16));

// Decrypt...
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  {
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(crypttext),
    salt: ""
  },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
  { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv) }
);

// Convert hex string to ASCII.
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889329/word-array-to-string
function hex2a(hex) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}

console.log(hex2a(plaintextArray.toString()));
```

The important bits are to specify no salt in your input and pass the key as a WordArray as jlvaquero says.  There are probably some efficiency improvements to be made, e.g. I'm guessing there's an easier way to convert a string to a WordArray than going to base64 and back, but at least it successfully decodes.  I lifted the hex2a function from StackOverflow question [Word Array to  String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889329/word-array-to-string).

Edit: I figured out how to convert strings to WordArrays and vice-versa with CryptoJS so the   extra base64 encode/decode and hex-to-ASCII function are not needed.  Also it turns out the salt property need not be specified.  This is more compact and efficient:

```
data = "IYkyGxYaNgHpnZWgwILMalVFmLWFgTCHCZL9263NOcfSo5lBjAzOZAtF5bF++R0Bi+9c9E+p3VEr/xvj4oABtRWVJ2wlWzLbYC2rKFk5iapFhb7uZCUpO4w4Su3a5QFa2vInjYueziRoqySZd/DpstMJ8rsJ94VGizFFFZ1l0sw1ax+wfBAv5+wHs/hlnHi/ea66KBO3rgXKahvV28h+4bh5etc8RCrmiiNbfg6Oj0jQJDjdYIdW8T9YPOI9E1hih8lbfRnMWcOFJgYekfLpoy5LI525UGnlM46J1k6ekLqsn9FqvbiOOoLgqa4YqBm1i9P0ePyjkME+t+RiL8xXX+ItgOYr9G7kM64wlTJPCW8B/crmUdmGzQNC/hD/u/8wfHBS2f8u6OtQMG/+Kpk1oju8lcUZGI/4S8A6/OuktvQr2zgnbs2aADMrM37Oait/pJ3G73S7NwVT8EaK+X43c0C/fUvW2/bD/rqCNpAh9WQlz4Cj6JHwjbmwuind6aCimF1tHjXuR9FXu+g17sPT4ZkKZ6aeBG+m170XdCGn2hVM0wH1rh3VeCG2u/JFqfuGKGSoqeHeNY/icu9pEhtZDzHd7aPoaMXcWvXC9PjooBf7GM1EPacSdnon1kBobjtKSt1l15DjO5TMrJoX7VO7GotQwo+uI/u5Kop01hBXxyxyggl1/8N0ESohPJoqLDrIwvbGK5kW4B49FVPnx9CMvjZDdSsoxPAh+hx6SPe8Hj0Nx4bRs06cbtOkte/V8QSYIqjiJDleEqPrdiKlvgToZz9L29ZR/3Ln65qU1sq7q9c0SEYxIopV7TdTjFS7y76zDPFZkhzc3DjfLtJo/M1hdtt648APcZdmAIgWH6fh3eJZ0qbiPh8RStYH7I2COmnlMw4+t/B5mlhYVSgwPK2Ir736Mh+P9Bw0fF8r9Ghhs4AJzpU0RiK9d1tCsrLfK/hSRwTXhtsSB6eDWEGkO7oeEIz43mgn0sv3SrA9JNHzYkg=";
key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05";

// Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
var rawData = atob(data);
var iv = rawData.substring(0,16);
var crypttext = rawData.substring(16);

// Decrypt...
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  { ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext) },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
  { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv) }
);

console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray));
```

Comment: I confirm this succeeds. He/she should get the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: You can prevent the extra Base64 encoding/decoding using CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse( binaryData ) to convert the binary string to WordArray.

Comment: just to mention it: Do NOT store your key in code! That is a huge security risk.

Comment: How do I provide key without hard-coding it in js file ?

Comment: I would recommend either  removing your first cut at this / snippet or put it *below* your final result with a note of it being the older/first attempt.

Answer (score 63):

This works for decryption using javascript.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/aes.js"></script>
var key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05";
var data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key); // Encryption Part
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); // Message
```

Guess I am a little late to the party.

Comment: When I do this `decrypted` is just an empty string. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is relevant. The question is asking how to decrypt a message using AES/CBC. Why are you using `.encrypt()`?

Comment: @jskidd3 I think its upvoted a lot because people are trying to use decrypt but getting weird results.  They do a search for CryptoJS.AES.decrypt and realize that the toString takes Utf8 as a parameter.  Its also one of the simplest examples of Crypto.JS that can easily be found.

Answer (score 3):

```
encryptWithCryptoJS(plainText: string): string {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("hf8685nfhfhjs9h8");
    const iv1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("hf8685nfhfhjs9h8");
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, key, {
        keySize: 16,
        iv: iv1,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return encrypted + "";
}

decryptionWithCryptoJS(cipher: string): string {
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("hf8685nfhfhjs9h8");
    const iv1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("hf8685nfhfhjs9h8");
    const plainText = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher, key, {
        keySize: 16,
        iv: iv1,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return plainText.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Comment: For me, this solution worked well. I was using Crypto-ES module as I was supposed to implement in Typescript. The keySize parameter is not applicable for for Crypto-ES. Otherwise it works wonders. Thank you so much ❤

Answer (score 0):

for the hex2a provided by another user, it may not working if ascii code is over 128 (i.e text contains chinese , etc)

you can use the follow to return proper unicode

```
function hex2a(hex) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2){

        var dec = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
        character = String.fromCharCode(dec);


        if (dec > 127)
            character = "%"+hex.substr(i,2);

        str += character;

    }

    return decodeURI(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
    var _enid = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key,
  {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return _enid;
```