# CryptoJS is not working with IV and key, but it works in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

So, I have the encryption and decryption methods on ruby and they work fine ruby. I followed the answer from [this question (How to decrypt message with CryptoJS AES. I have a working Ruby example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22601457/2355163) but it's returning an empty string.

**Ruby Code**

```
def load_vars
        @key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05"
        @algorithm = "aes-128-cbc"
    end

    def encryption(data)
        begin
            key = @key
            aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(@algorithm)
            aes.encrypt()
            aes.key = key
            iv_value = aes.random_iv
            aes.iv = iv_value
            crypt = aes.update(data) + aes.final()
            crypt_string = (Base64.encode64(iv_value + crypt))
            return crypt_string
        end
    end

    def decryption(data)
        begin
            key = @key
            aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(@algorithm)
            iv_value = Base64.decode64(data)[0...16]
            data_value = Base64.decode64(data)[16..-1]
            aes.decrypt
            aes.key = @key
            aes.iv = iv_value
            results = aes.update(data_value) + aes.final
            return results
        end
    end
```

**HTML**
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ynofacL7/)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/core-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>        
    data = "wlkAKa4ps+Xizx4VIdUSp43yfQvOmt9FNlVTQ1ANsCU=\n"; // The data received from the ruby encryption method
    key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05";

    // Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
    var rawData = atob(data);
    var iv = rawData.substring(0,16);
    var crypttext = rawData.substring(16);

    // Decrypt...
    var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      { ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext) },
      CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
      { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv) }
    );

    console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray));
</script>
```

Comment: your javascript code is correct since it works with the `data` value of  the link, so the issue is in the Ruby code. I think the problem is in the `key` parameter. When  encrypting you are directly passing a hexadecimal, but you should provide the decoded value. Could you try with `aes.key = key.scan(/../).collect{ |x| x.hex }.pack('c*')`  (extracted from your link). I'm afraid I can not be more specific because I do not know Ruby

Comment: Can you provide the original (plaintext) data that generated the encrypted data: `data = "wlkAKa4ps+Xizx4VIdUSp43yfQvOmt9FNlVTQ1ANsCU=\n";`? 
Having the original data we can implement the encrypt method that generates it and from there, debug.

Comment: @SuthanBala, did you try with the code I haved provided to convert HEX key to bytes?

Comment: @pedrofb yes I did, no luck.

Comment: Please, include the original text and the encrypted data with using HEX key converted as I suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Ruby expects the key to be in binary format, not hex. So you need to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

data = "When in Rome do as the Romans do"
key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05"
aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
aes.encrypt()
aes.key = key.scan(/../).collect{|x| x.hex}.pack("c*")
iv_value = aes.random_iv
aes.iv = iv_value
crypt = aes.update(data) + aes.final()
crypt_string = (Base64.encode64(iv_value + crypt))
puts crypt_string
```

For me that prints

```
mdnLCY6MdwEONY1AxR/vjVKMssB+yrPsz4QMjfl6fDXxv68E0EUxtAqa4VUo
fTkjq2Hqyd48UV3dyWmEbwXw5Q==
```

If I put that into your HTML file (without changing any code), I get back the original message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/core-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>        
data = "mdnLCY6MdwEONY1AxR/vjVKMssB+yrPsz4QMjfl6fDXxv68E0EUxtAqa4VUo\nfTkjq2Hqyd48UV3dyWmEbwXw5Q==\n";
key = "2e35f242a46d67eeb74aabc37d5e5d05";

var rawData = atob(data);
var iv = rawData.substring(0,16);
var crypttext = rawData.substring(16);

// Decrypt...
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  { ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(crypttext) },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
  { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(iv) }
);

console.log(plaintextArray);
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So the problem is that your Ruby code produced a gibberish cyphertext. Fix the key and re-encrypt, and the JS should start working.

Comment: This is not the same as my comment?

Comment: This works in JavaScript now, thank you. But, this breaks the decryption method in ruby that was working before.

Comment: To fix Ruby decryption, you have to change how you set the key there too (so it matches the encryption side).