# Cannot read property 'salt' of undefined Node js Crypto-js

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

My Code working with debug but when I try to run giving this error . Why It's happens.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
require('dotenv').config();

getText = process.env.USER;

var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(getText, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 
console.log(originalText);
```

and when I try read from .env giving this error.

Comment: is `process.env.USER` defined? Can you `console.log` it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt message with CryptoJS AES. I have a working Ruby example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958103/how-to-decrypt-message-with-cryptojs-aes-i-have-a-working-ruby-example)

Comment: @eol yes That is not undefined When  ı run with debugger There is no problem. but When ı run  giving this err

Answer (score 4):

This happens when getText is null or undefined

Comment: Affirmative. In other words, the error occurs when the _plaintext_ you are trying to encrypt is *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

I have same yours and found my solutions:

Possibly: Check again your data encrypt, is that encrypt in a right way ? same key, same library ? json.stringify and json.parse ? Your .env file set up right ? Cause you don't show that code so we can not give more details.